# Paginación con React no termina de funcionar, se sigue mostrando todos los items en pantalla

Tags: reactjs, paginacion

Hola que tal tengo una paginación hecha con un paquete de react llamada react-paginate aquí os dejo el link de la doc.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paginate

Lo he implementado en mi App que es un diario de notas, el usuario crea notas y estas dinámicamente se van guardando en el localStorage y se muestran en pantalla, pues bien, he establecido que haya 6 notas por página, es decir, cuando haya una séptima nota, no debería mostrarse a menos que el usuario vaya a la página 2, cuando hayan 13 notas página 3 y así...

La funcionalidad de mi componente que he llamado `Pagination` funciona correctamente, es dinámico, tengo ahora mismo testeando 13 notas, por lo que me muestra 3 páginas, si tuviera 12, me mostraría 2.

El problema es que a pesar de que mi paginación es correcta, las 13 notas se están mostrando en pantalla, cuando debería ser 6 - 6 - 1

Os dejo el código para ver si localizamos el fallo, un saludo y gracias de antemano.

El prop que recibe `Pagination` llamado data, son básicamente las notas que se crean dinámicamente en `App.js`. `const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);`

Componente `Pagination`

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate';
import '../styles/Pagination.css';

const Pagination = (props) => {
  const { data } = props;
    
  // We start with an empty list of items.
  const [currentItems, setCurrentItems] = useState([]); //antes era null en lugar de array []
  const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
  // Here we use item offsets; we could also use page offsets
  // following the API or data you're working with.
  const [itemOffset, setItemOffset] = useState(0);
    const itemsPerPage = 6;

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch items from another resources.
    const endOffset = itemOffset + itemsPerPage;
    console.log(`Loading items from ${itemOffset} to ${endOffset}`);
    setCurrentItems(data.slice(itemOffset, endOffset));
    setPageCount(Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage));
  }, [itemOffset, itemsPerPage, data]);

  // Invoke when user click to request another page.
  const handlePageClick = (event) => {
  const newOffset = (event.selected * itemsPerPage) % data.length;
  console.log(
    `User requested page number ${event.selected}, which is offset ${newOffset}`
  );
  setItemOffset(newOffset);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ReactPaginate
        breakLabel="..."
        nextLabel="next >"
        onPageChange={handlePageClick}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        pageCount={pageCount}
        previousLabel="< previous"
        renderOnZeroPageCount={null}
                containerClassName="pagination"
                pageLinkClassName="page-num"
                previousLinkClassName="page-num"
                nextLinkClassName="page-num"
                activeLinkClassName="activee boxx"
      />
    </>
  );
}

export default Pagination;
```

En el componente `App.js` hago uso de mi componente `Pagination`

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import NoteList from "./components/NoteList";
import './App.css';
import Search from "./components/Search";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Pagination from "./components/Pagination";

const App = () => {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
   const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false); //cambia el template de la app
   //Se encarga de mostrar la nota para escribir 
   const [showNote, setShowNote] = useState(true); //eslint-disable-line
  useEffect(() => {
    const saveNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes-data'));
    if (saveNotes){
      setNotes(saveNotes);
    }
    
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('notes-data', JSON.stringify(notes))
  },[notes])

  const addNote = (inputText, text) => { //ese text, es el texto úncamente del textArea
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }
  const deleteNote = (id) => {
    var response = window.confirm("¿Estás seguro de que deseas eliminar la nota?");
    if (response){
      const notesUpdated = notes.filter((note) => note.id !== id)
      setNotes(notesUpdated);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className={darkMode ? 'dark-mode' : ''}>

    <div className="container">
      <Header 
        handleToggleTheme={setDarkMode}
      />
      <Search 
        handleSearchNote={setSearchText}
        setShowNote={setShowNote}
        />
      <NoteList 
        notes={notes.filter((noteText) => 
          noteText.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
        )}
        handleAddNote={addNote}
        handleDeleteNote={deleteNote}
      />
      <Pagination data={notes}/>
    </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Imagen para dar un poco de contexto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no use nunca este componente, pero por lo que me parece, puede que el problema de que se muestren todos no sea de este componente, si no del componente en los que muestras las cards. Por lo que veo pagination no te muestra componente, si no solo en control de páginas. yo creo que la función onpagechange la tendrías que tener en el componente padre y pasarsela a tu componente pagination, y controlar la página en app, luego pasarle la página a notelist o en función de la página pasarle directamente la lista al componente notelist

Comment: Segun la documentacion itemsPerPage es una prop que tenes que pasarle al componente, pero vos la redeclaras en el mismo componente. Tendra algo que ver?  ``<Pagination itemsPerPage={6} data={notes}/>``

Comment: Hola @AgustinG. lo he probado pero el resultado es el mismo, solamente estaría pasando la variable por props. En realidad funciona porque he probado únicamente a coger los títulos de las notas y pasarlos al componente pagination, pero aún así las notas siguen apareciendo, no consigo seleccionar el componente de las notas.

Comment: @Suso Ya está solucionado el tema, mi componente ` NoteList ` que se encarga de mostrar las notas del componente Note.js debía estar en Pagination al que **debía usar la vairable currentItems** que no estaba usando, finalmente en el componente padre App.js donde se renderiza Pagination, pasarle por props el contenido de NoteList. Gracias por tu tiempo!